# Pgfplots: Addplot color depending on sign

Tags: pgfplots

I want to create a plot where positive and negative values have a different color. MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
-3.5 nan
-3.375 nan
-3.25 nan
-3.125 0.000121769833828
-3.0 0.000901599938148
-2.875 0.0014834598325
-2.625 0.00588102803508
-2.25 0.0720113632674
-2.125 0.0314393757219
-1.875 0.0306933267171
-1.75 0.07029144932
-1.375 -0.0342012822215
-1.125 -0.0171975784671
-0.75 -0.0405296273749
-0.625 -0.0330713662613
-0.375 -0.00156002201142
0.0 0.044002036309
0.125 0.0634327667271
0.375 0.0153149732892
0.75 -0.00313272843988
0.875 0.0229547104663
1.125 0.0219197613133
1.625 0.0112441717079
1.875 -0.000229179659447
2.0 nan
2.625 nan
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{onlyPositive/.style={y filter/.code={
        \pgfmathparse{##1<0 ? nan : ##1}}, unbounded coords=jump}}
\pgfplotsset{onlyNegative/.style={y filter/.code={
        \pgfmathparse{##1>=0 ? nan : ##1}}, unbounded coords=jump}}
  \begin{axis}[grid]
    \addplot [] file {data.txt};
    \addplot [onlyPositive,blue,xshift=2mm,very thick] file {data.txt};
    \addplot [onlyNegative,red,xshift=2mm,very thick] file {data.txt};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now, I want for example the graphs positive part be blue, negative be red. I tried math. expressions to add 2 plots, one for neg, one for pos. But then, there are holes in the graph between sign change, since I have two plots now (as you can see in the figure). What I really want is that the color automatically changes on the lines.[image]

Thank you for helping me out!
Max

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Seeing also one of your failed attempts might help.

Comment: In your real application, do you use a line plot for displaying your data, or a scatter plot? If you use a line plot, if you have a sign change between two consecutive data points, do you want the line to change colour midway?

Comment: I added a larger MWE, expressing my intent more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is some kind of decomposition into intersection segments of your path with the X axis.

There is the `fillbetween` library in `pgfplots` which allows to compute (and, typically, fill) intersection segments of path segments. It can also be used to draw individual intersection segments:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
-3.5 nan
-3.375 nan
-3.25 nan
-3.125 0.000121769833828
-3.0 0.000901599938148
-2.875 0.0014834598325
-2.625 0.00588102803508
-2.25 0.0720113632674
-2.125 0.0314393757219
-1.875 0.0306933267171
-1.75 0.07029144932
-1.375 -0.0342012822215
-1.125 -0.0171975784671
-0.75 -0.0405296273749
-0.625 -0.0330713662613
-0.375 -0.00156002201142
0.0 0.044002036309
0.125 0.0634327667271
0.375 0.0153149732892
0.75 -0.00313272843988
0.875 0.0229547104663
1.125 0.0219197613133
1.625 0.0112441717079
1.875 -0.000229179659447
2.0 nan
2.625 nan
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[grid]
    \addplot [draw=none,name path=PATH] file {data.txt};
    \path[name path=0 line] (-10,0) -- (10,0);

    \draw[
        intersection segments={
            of=0 line and PATH,
            sequence=R2 R4 R6}, 
        blue, very thick];
    \draw[
        intersection segments={
            of=0 line and PATH,
            sequence=R3 R5}, 
        red, very thick];
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you see, the approach is less automatic than a math expression. However, it is much more precise: the intersections are computed explicitly and each segment can be addressed and drawn explicitly. The syntax inside of `sequence` is that `L1` is the first segment of the `L`eft input segment (called `0 line` here) and `R1` is the first segment of the `R`right input segment (called `PATH` here). I draw every second segment; the start offset and the end segment is manual work.

Comment: Thank you for this example. Usually, this would solve the problem, so I marked it accordingly. Unfortunately, I was looking for a fully-automatic approach, as I automatically generate these plots.
What I did in this case: Since my data is in a file, I could run another (external program) filter on the data, which linearly interpolates between sign changes and hence adds zeros to the graph. Then I could use the onlyPositive and onlyNegative styles to automatically achieve my solution.

Comment: @Christian Feuersänger I too need this functionality in an automated fashion. I tried using ``y expr={max(\thisrow{\colname},0)`` but of course the slope is different for the lines above and below the axis and ``smooth`` does not work. Is there a way we can do this like a point meta function of ``y``?

Comment: @SpmP I will take a note on it for my list of feature reqests, I see its uses. In fact, I considered such an approach and postponed it when I wrote the initial version of `fillbetween`. However, the use of `point meta` might turn out to be difficult in this context. I will think about solutions.

Comment: @Christian Feuersänger I had partial success with ``\addplot+[black, mark = none,mesh, shader=flat corner,point meta = (y<0)-(y>0)] table ...;`` but of course the line did not change colour neatly at the zero. Look forward to your solution. Where do can we see your progress on such things?

Comment: @SpmP the progress can be seen by (a) watching for changes in the "unstable" section on http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/ and/or (b) by subscribing as commit watcher on https://sourceforge.net/projects/pgfplots/. To this end you might need a  sourceforge login.