# Pgfplots set color of addplot depending on the first row in the table

Tags: pgfplots

The following code plots data from two files. How can I modify the code such that the color of addplot is chosen depending on which quadrant the first x-y pair in the data file belongs to? For example, assume that I want plots originating in the second and third quadrants to be green and magenta, respectively, then tmp1.dat and tmp2.dat should be plotted in green and magenta, respectively.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{tmp1.dat}
  x y
  -1 1
  0 0
  1 1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{tmp2.dat}
  x y
  -1 -1
  0 0
  1 -1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \foreach \i in {1,2}
    {
      \addplot table {tmp\i.dat};
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I think [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94150/how-to-read-value-from-table-assign-to-variable-and-use-it-in-x-expr-thisrow) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207042/pgfplots-addplot-color-depending-on-sign) may be relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This reads the *first* coordinate from the data files and colors the plots accordingly. The list of colors is stored in `\LstColors` and the numbering of the quadrants is, let's say, unconventional but can be changed.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\newcommand*{\ReadOutElement}[4]{%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#2}{[index]#3}\of{#1}%
    \let#4\pgfplotsretval}
\def\LstColors{"green","magenta","orange","red"}    
\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{tmp1.dat}
  x y
  -1 1
  0 0
  1 1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{tmp2.dat}
  x y
  -1 -1
  0 0
  1 -1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \foreach \i in {1,2}
    {\pgfplotstableread{tmp\i.dat}\datatable
      \ReadOutElement{\datatable}{0}{0}{\myx}
      \ReadOutElement{\datatable}{0}{1}{\myy}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\quadrant}{2*ifthenelse(\myx<0,0,1)+ifthenelse(\myy<0,0,1)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{{\LstColors}[\quadrant]}
      \edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot[color=\mycolor] table {tmp\i.dat};} 
      \temp
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! My understanding is that each file is opened twice, by `\pgfplotstableread` and `\addplot`. Would it be more efficient to reuse `\datatable`; `\addplot[...] table {\datatable}`? I tried this but I get the error "Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file '{x}{y}' in 'search path=.'plotstable manual for details). };". I suppose it has to do with the pointer of the filereader pointing at the tables second line. How do I fix this? Related, is there any reason why `\pgfplotstablegetelem` are left out of _Manual for Package PGFPLOTS_, version 1.16, and _TikZ&PGF Manual_, version 3.1?

Comment: @Angelos Please note that plotting a table from a file and plotting a loaded table are not precisely the same, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/356790. This is why I decided to open the file twice is the simpler solution. (I also do not precisely understand what you are trying to do.) `\pgfplotstablegetelem` can be found in the manual for `pgfplotstable`.

Comment: @Angelos BTW, `\edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot[color=\mycolor] table {\noexpand\datatable};} 
      \temp` does work, so I really do not know what issue you are referring to. I nevertheless advise to "open the file twice".

Comment: I understand. Aha, I think the reason I failed to reuse `\datatable` is that I omitted `\noexpand`. The command `\noexpand` is a command I have to learn more about.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the following is the desired output, you can use `\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist` as shown in the below MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}



\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mylist}{%
  draw=magenta,every mark/.append style={solid, fill=magenta},mark=*\\ %1
  draw=green,every mark/.append style={solid,fill=green}, mark=*\\%2
}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{tmp1.dat}
  x y
  -1 1
  0 0
  1 1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{tmp2.dat}
  x y
  -1 -1
  0 0
  1 -1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[cycle list name=mylist]
    \foreach \i in {1,2}
    {
      \addplot table {tmp\i.dat};
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. The output is as I specified in my example. However, this solution is limited since it requires the data files to have a known order. In my use case the order is unknown. The solution I am seeking uses the content of the data file to determine the color.